# Create reusable and configurable branded components

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitextfield, uilabel, subclass

I am developing a bunch of apps for a company, where the UI components (labels, buttons, textfields etc.) will be strongly branded with custom fonts, different font sizes, colors etc. Because there are some minor variations, I would like to take an approach of creating reusable and configurable subclasses.

So my idea is to subclass `UILabel`, `UIButton`, `UITextField` etc. and have a separate config file (e.g. a constants file with `structs` in it, which define colors, `UIFont` styles, text sizes etc. and make the subclass use it (or give certain configurable inits, e.g. init with `headerStyle1`).

Is there already an existing framework for Swift for this or does anyone have experience how to best do this?

Comment: extensions maybe

Comment: You probably are looking for UIAppearance class which helps you with these configurations.